# Collecting data from an amplify website to dynamodb with an API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, python-3.7, aws-amplify

I am unable to write data from the wedsite to my dynamodb and I've tried everything I can think of... I've tried numpy, =event, user.input and many others... maybe I'm doing it wrong but I can't figure it out right now as you can see I've got all the imports I should need but it's still not working.

```
import boto3    # Python AWS SDK
import json     # Used for handling API-based data.
import base64   # Needed to decode the incoming POST data
import random   # Needed for random number generator

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Perform JSON data decoding 
    body_enc = event['body']
    dec_dict = json.loads(base64.b64decode(body_enc))

    # Note that all of the POST data from our website form can now 
    # be accessed via the `dec_dict` dictionary object. 
    # For example, if we entered the name field as 'Student_name on the website' :
    # >>> dec_dict['name']
    # 'Student_name'

 # --- Write to dynamodb ---
    
    # ** Create a variable that can take a random value between 1 and 1 000 000 000. 
    # This variable will be used as our key value i.e the ResponsesID and should be of type integer.
    # It is important to note that the ResponseID i.e. the rid variable, should take
    # on a unique value to prevent errors when writing to DynamoDB. **
    
    # --- Insert your code here ---
    rid = random.randint(1, 1000000000) # <--- Replace this value with your code.
    # -----------------------------
    
    # ** Instantiate the DynamoDB service with the help of the boto3 library **
    
    # --- Insert your code here ---
    dynamodb = boto3.resource ('dynamodb' , region_name = 'eu-west-1') # <--- Replace this value with your code.
    # -----------------------------
    
    # Instantiate the table. Remember pass the name of the DynamoDB table created in step 4
    table = dynamodb.Table('EDSA_Cloud_Computing')
    
    # ** Write the responses to the table using the put_item method. **

    # Complete the below code so that the appropriate 
    # incoming data is sent to the matching column in your DynamoDB table
    # --- Insert your code here ---
    db_response = table.put_item(Item={'ResponsesID': rid, # <--- Insert the correct variable
                        'Name':data['name'], # <--- Insert the correct variable
                        'Email':data['email'], # <--- Insert the correct variable
                        'Cell':data['phone'], # <--- Insert the correct variable
                        'Message':data['message'] # <--- Insert the correct variable
    })
    # -----------------------------
    
    
    # Create a response object to tell the website that the form data 
    # was successfully received. We use the contents of the decoded JSON dictionary
    # to create this response. As the predict progresses, we'll include 
    # more information about the AWS services we will invoke. 
    lambda_response = {
        'statusCode': 200, # <-- Tells the website that everything executed successfully.
        'body': json.dumps({
        'Name': dec_dict['name'],
        'Email': dec_dict['email'],
        'Cell': dec_dict['phone'], 
        'Message': dec_dict['message']
        })
    }

    return lambda_response
```

[Log report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S7Ko.png)

Comment: What is the error, that you are getting ?

Comment: Response
{
  "errorMessage": "'body'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 24, in lambda_handler\n    body_enc = event['body']\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 0b21a7d2-1d44-47b9-8d86-76a4e09eb879 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] KeyError: 'body'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in lambda_handler
    body_enc = event['body']
END RequestId: 0b21a7d2-1d44-47b9-8d86-76a4e09eb879
REPORT RequestId: 0b21a7d2-1d44-47b9-8d86-76a4e09eb879

Comment: Please try to print the event and its keys using `print(event)` and `print(event.keys())`  and then add the output log in the question, so that we can understand the event that you are receiving to help you.

Comment: How do you do that in Lambda? sorry newbie at it... lol

Comment: You can go to aws cloudwatch service--> logs-->logs group --> your function log stream will be there --> check the latest log stream and there you will see the output.

Comment: Added an image called Log report

Comment: Could you please update the above code because the current code above doesn't have line 73.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.